# Changing Multiple Values in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The sample of the dataset I am working on:

```py
test = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2),
                                   (1,3),
                                   (4,5)],
                                  ['cod_item_2','alter_cod'])
```

[image]

```py
test_2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,"shamp_1"),(2,"shamp_2"),
                                     (4,"tire_1"),(5,"tire_2"),
                                     (3,"shamp_3"),(6,"cookie"),
                                     (7,"flower"),(8,"water")],
                                    ['cod_item','product_name'])
```

[image]

The first dataframe contains items and items that are equivalent to them.

The second dataframe contains all items and product names.

I want to use the first dataframe to pull out the items that are equivalent to the second dataframe and replace with the item that represents them (the item on the left side of the first table), where the result is as follows:

[image]

I tried doing a full join on both dataframes and using the `when` clause to change the values. But it ended up not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do 2 joins. `test_2` with `test` and then again with `test_2` (self join). For this to work reliably I use `alias` on dataframes.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

test_3 = (
    test_2.alias('a')
    .join(test, F.col("a.cod_item") == F.col("alter_cod"), "left")
    .join(test_2.alias('b'), F.col("cod_item_2") == F.col("b.cod_item"), "left")
    .select(
        F.coalesce("b.cod_item", "a.cod_item").alias("cod_item"),
        F.coalesce("b.product_name", "a.product_name").alias("product_name")
    )
)
test_3.show()
# +--------+------------+
# |cod_item|product_name|
# +--------+------------+
# |       4|      tire_1|
# |       1|     shamp_1|
# |       1|     shamp_1|
# |       4|      tire_1|
# |       7|      flower|
# |       6|      cookie|
# |       1|     shamp_1|
# |       8|       water|
# +--------+------------+
```

Comment: If the test_2 data frame is a shopping table (eg item shamp_1 appears repeatedly in it) the result of the joins ends up repeating the shamp_1 value even more (eg if has 3 items shamp_1, the join will results in 9 items instead of 5). How to fix this error?

Comment: Before creating `test_3`, remove duplicates from test_2: `test_2 = test_2.distinct()`

Comment: I understood. I ended up specifying the problem wrong, sorry for that. The correct thing would be to have another column: customer_ID.
That way, it wouldn't be possible to drop duplicate items because I lose purchase information. But thanks so much for the help so far.